# How to make find return in the same order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Consider this:

```
ids = [14195, 6053, 53119, 7513, 5161, 43252, 7633, 627, 54644, 1438]
```

`Foo.find(ids).map(&:id)` returns:

```
[627, 1438, 5161, 6053, 7513, 7633, 14195, 43252, 53119, 54644]
```

Any way I can make `find` return the results in the same order they were put in? i.e.:

```
[14195, 6053, 53119, 7513, 5161, 43252, 7633, 627, 54644, 1438]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055138/mysql-sort-order-by-array-value)

```
Foo.where(:id => ids).order("field(id, 627, 1438, 5161, 6053, 7513, 7633, 14195, 43252, 53119, 54644").map(&:id)
```

OR with `where`

```
Foo.where(:id => ids).order("field(id, #{ids.join(',')})").map(&:id)
```

OR with `find`

```
Foo.find(ids, :order =>"field(id, #{ids.join(',')})").map(&:id)
```