# sort rows by a custom array

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to sort rows by a custom array of `ids` given from another table or somehow.

```
$str = "5,2,3,6,911,18,118,65,985,15...";  

$arr = explode(',', $str);

function get_titles($status){
    global $db;
    $sql = "select * from arts where status = :astatus order by " . $arr . " asc";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([":astatus" => $status]);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL sort order by array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055138/mysql-sort-order-by-array-value)

Comment: @Sean, both answers on your link are about `sort by field`. I have no a field as sort criteria, but an external array.

Comment: the field is what to order by. Your array is the additional values. ie. `... ORDER BY field(id, ". $str .") ...`

Comment: If the answer is correct please approve it

Answer (score 0):

If you want order by custom `id` order...

```
# $str = "5,2,3,6,911,18,118,65,985,15...";
# Values separated by comma
# It can be from array
#     $str = implode(",",[5,2,3,6,911,18,118,65,985,15])

$str = "5,2,3,6,911,18,118,65,985,15";  

function get_titles($status,$arr){
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM arts WHERE status = :astatus ORDER BY FIELD(id,".$arr .") ASC";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([":astatus" => $status]);
    ...
}

get_titles($status,$str)
```