# select where in - custom order

Tags: php, mysql

```
$str = "25,12,13,19";  

$sql = "select id, src, link from banners where id in (" . $str . ")";
```

This works but rows are ordered this way - `12,13,19,25`

How can I get the rows ordered by `$str` values, i.e. - `25,12,13,19` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL sort order by array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055138/mysql-sort-order-by-array-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you explicitly sort the result, the engine is free to return the rows of the result in any order. To sort a result you have to include an `ORDER BY` clause. Here you can use `field()`. It gets the position of a value in a list of values.

```
SELECT d,
       src,
       link
       FROM banners
       WHERE id IN (25, 12, 13, 19)
       ORDER BY field(id, 25, 12, 13, 19);
```