# MySQL sort order by array value of selected table

Tags: mysql

With e.g.

```
ORDER BY field(id, 9, 1, 4)
```

I can order by 9,1,4.

Is it also possible to order by a comma separated string of the same table I am selecting?

I tried

```
ORDER BY field(id, aFieldFromTheTableIAmSelecting)
```

where aFieldFromTheTableIAmSelecting is "9,1,4"

But that does not work.

This question is similiar to [MySQL sort order by array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055138/mysql-sort-order-by-array-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `find_in_set()`:

```
ORDER BY find_in_set(id, aFieldFromTheTableIAmSelecting)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`locate()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate):

```
ORDER BY locate(concat(',', id, ','), concat(',', aFieldFromTheTableIAmSelecting, ','))
```

there must be no spaces inside `aFieldFromTheTableIAmSelecting`.